# Attempting to read in a file and storing the first input in an array val and the second input in an array wt (weight)

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, fopen, feof

I need to read in a file called "data.txt" and store the first input as a value and the second corresponding input as a weight. I'm having issues reading them in and storing the values.

```
data.txt (example)

3 25
2 20
1 15
4 40
5 50
```

This is what I´ve started with:

```
FILE *myFile;
myFile=fopen("data.txt", "r");


int val[20]={0}; //initialize value array to zero
int wt[20]={0}; 
int W=80; //Set capacity to 80
int i;
int n;

while(!feof(myFile)){ 
  fscanf(myFile, "%1d%1d", &val[i], &wt[i]);
}

n = sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]);
printf("%d", knapSack(W, wt, val, n));//prints out the maximum value
fclose(myFile);
return 0;
```

I've edited the above code to the following:

```
FILE *myFile;
myFile=fopen("data.txt", "r");


int val[20]={0};
int wt[20]={0};
int W=80; //Set capacity to 80
int i;
int n;

for(i=0;i<sizeof(val);i++){
  fscanf(myFile, "%1d%1d", &wt[i],&val[i]);
}

n = sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]);
printf("%d", knapSack(W, wt, val, n));//prints out the maximum value
fclose(myFile);
return 0;
```

It keeps outputting 55 when I use the inputs from the data.txt example.

Comment: Can you please elaborate exactly what errors or incorrect behaviours you are seeing? "having issues" is not a very informative description. What issues precisely?

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Thank you, It was not outputting anything so I assumed it was how I was storing val and wt from the file.

Comment: You may make life easier with `struct mydata  { int val; int wt; };` Then you can simply create your array `strct mydata arr[20] = {{ .val = 0; }};` Now you can coordinate each `val` and `wt` as a single object, e.g. `arr[0].val` and `arr[0].wt;`, etc..Read a line at a time with either `size_t n = 0; while (fscanf(myfile, "%d %d", &arr[n].val, &arr[n].wt) == 2) { n++; }` Now you have your filled array of struct and your number of elements `n`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `myFile=fopen("data.txt", "r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this: `for(i=0;i<sizeof(val);i++){` will write past the end of the array `val[]`   because `sizeof` returns the number of bytes not the number of integers.  Suggest: `for(i=0;i<(sizeof(val) / sizeof( val[0] );i++){`

Comment: regarding: `while(!feof(myFile)){ 
  fscanf(myFile, "%1d%1d", &val[i], &wt[i]);
}`  This neither initializes nor increments `i` so what ever random value in on the stack where `i` is located will be used

Comment: strongly suggest the `while()` loop use the returned value from `fscanf()` as the controlling value, not `feof()`

Comment: when asking a question about a run-time problem (as this question is doing) please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem you are having is you are not controlling your read-loop with the return of the read itself. For example, in your case you would want:

```
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(myFile, "%1d%1d", &wt[i],&val[i]) == 2)
    i++;
```

At the end of your read, `i` would hold the number of elements read into your arrays.

(**note:** you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return...***)

Instead of reading the values into separate arrays, whenever you are coordinating multiple values as a single object (e.g. each `val` and `wt` pair), you should be thinking `struct`. That allows you to coordinate both values as a single object.

A simple example in your case could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXVAL 20   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct {    /* struct with int val, wt + typdef for conveninece */
    int val, wt;
} mydata;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t n = 0;                           /* number of elements read */
    mydata arr[MAXVAL] = {{ .val = 0 }};    /* array of mydtata */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read all pairs of values in file into array */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d", &arr[n].val, &arr[n].wt) == 2)
        n++;

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)  /* output values */
        printf ("arr[%zu]  %2d  %2d\n", i, arr[i].val, arr[i].wt);
}
```

Above, the code does the same as I suggested in conditioning the read-loop on successfully reading a pair of values from the file. The only difference is that is coordinates the `val` and `wt` values in a struct.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `dat/val_wt.txt`, you would receive the following output:

```
$ ./bin/read_val_wt dat/val_wt.txt
arr[0]   3  25
arr[1]   2  20
arr[2]   1  15
arr[3]   4  40
arr[4]   5  50
```

While above we read directly with `fscanf`, you can make your read a bit more robust by reading each line into a character array first, and then parsing the wanted values from the character array with `sscanf`. You are essentially doing the same thing, but by using `fgets/sscanf` you can make an independent validation of (1) the read of the line; and (2) the parse of the wanted information from the line. If you have a malformed-line, it prevents the *matching-failure* from impacting the read of the remaining lines in the input file.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, many little problems here...

First even if unrelated, you consistenly fail to check the result of input functions. It can lead to hide problems...

Next, the rule is *when you do not get what you would expect, **trace** intermediary values*.

Had you happen those lines:

```
// uncomment next block for debugging
printf("n=%d\n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d %d\n", wt[i], val[i]);
}
```

You would have seen

```
n = 20
3 2
5 2
2 0
1 1
5 4
4 0
5 5
0
```

showing that:

- n was 20 (unsure whether you expected it)
- you had read your values one **digit** at a time instead of one integer value (because of the `%1d` formats)

My advice:

```
for (i = 0; i<sizeof(val); i++) {        // do not try to read more than array capacity
    if (2 != fscanf(myFile, "%d%d", &wt[i], &val[i])) break;  // stop when no more data
}

n = i;     // number of actual values

// uncomment next block for debugging
/*
printf("n=%d\n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d %d\n", wt[i], val[i]);
}
*/
```